# Task.WaitAll is blocking

Tags: c#, async-await

I want to run two tasks simultaneously, with one having a Task.Delay() in it.

i.e. one runs continuously and one runs every 15 minutes.

Here's what I have so far:

```
public class ContinousAndAggregatedCheckRunner<T, T2>                                                             
{
   private readonly int _aggregationInterval;
   private readonly List<T> _collectedData;
   private readonly Func<IEnumerable<T>, Task<T2>> _aggregator;
   private readonly Func<Task<IEnumerable<T>>> _collector;
   private CancellationToken _aggregationToken = default(CancellationToken);
   private CancellationToken _collectionToken = default(CancellationToken);

   public ContinousAndAggregatedCheckRunner(Func<IEnumerable<T>, Task<T2>> aggregator,
                                            int aggregationInterval,
                                            Func<Task<IEnumerable<T>>>)
   {
      _aggregator = aggregator;
      _aggregationInterval = aggregationInterval;
      _collector = collector;
      _collectedData = new List<T>();
   }

   public async Task Run()
   {
       Task.WaitAll(Collect(), Aggregate());     
   }

   private async Task Collect()
   {
      while (!_collectionToken.IsCancellationRequested)
      {
          Console.WriteLine($"Collecting {DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()} {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}");
          try
          {
             var results = await _collector();
             _collectedData.AddRange(results);
          }
          catch (TaskCanceledException)
          {
              break;
          }
       }
    }

    private async Task Aggregate()
    {
       while (!_aggregationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
       {
         Console.WriteLine("Aggregating");
                try
                {
                    var aggregate = await _aggregator(_collectedData);
                    var taskFactory = new TaskFactory();
                    await taskFactory.StartNew(() => Send(aggregate), _aggregationToken);
                    _collectedData.Clear();
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(_aggregationInterval), _aggregationToken);
                }
                catch (TaskCanceledException)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem is, it runs collecting for a bit. Then it comes into Aggregate() and it stops doing anything for the Task.Delay() then it `Sends()`. Then it does nothing again.

By does nothing, I mean Collect() stops executing.

I assume at some point it is blocking.

Is their a pattern here I'm missing. I want to run two tasks indefinitely and allow one of them to `pause` for a specified amount of time without affecting the other.

Comment: what is _collectionToken and _aggretationToken and where is .IsCancellationRequested managed for each?

Comment: @Marshall Tigerus, I've edited the post, right now I just have them as default(CancellationToken) in the class as private members. I haven't got round to implementing cancellation stuff yet.

Comment: Are you certain you aren't hitting your exception blocks?  That would end either method.

Comment: As an aside, `List<T>` is not thread safe and you're concurrently adding, reading and clearing it.

Comment: Your `Run()` method is very badly behaved.  Yes, it blocks, very bad for an `async` method.  You should use `WhenAll` rather than `WaitAll`.  Simplest fix: `void Task Run() { return Task.WhenAll(Collect(), Aggregate()); }`

Comment: @Marshall Tigerus, I'm definitely not throwing TaskCancelledException anywhere... It's just I see the console.WriteLine("Collecting") just stop updating after a while.

Comment: @Ben Voigt, is their a better pattern for doing stuff like this? Running two tasks side by side with them able to both have Task.Delay() within?

Comment: @Stuart At first read the docs about Task. You should have noticed that Task.WaitAll will block (it is documented). After docs read the blog from Stephen Cleary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a couple of things that could be fixed.

1. As it said by Ben Voigt, "WaitAll" is really a blocker, you'd better to make a sequence of tasks with WhenAll
2. It can be worth to use Task.Factory.StartNew instead of instatiating new TaskFactory instance
3. StartNew may be not a best choice at all, see details here https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html